# Mini-Cart displaying Parent Product Image instead of Product Image

Tags: product, cart, image, ajax

I've got code that will display a product in the mini-cart using ajax, when a customer clicks on Add to Cart. The issue is that it is not displaying the child product image until I do a refresh of that page, instead it shows the Parent Product Image. I've gone into the back end and changed "Configurable Product Image" and "Grouped Product Image" to display the product Image however it seems that the code below is ignoring these settings:

```
<?php
    $_item = $this->getItem();
    $isVisibleProduct = $_item->getProduct()->isVisibleInSiteVisibility();
    $canApplyMsrp = Mage::helper('catalog')->canApplyMsrp($_item->getProduct(), Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Attribute_Source_Msrp_Type::TYPE_BEFORE_ORDER_CONFIRM);
?>
<li class="item">
    <?php if ($this->hasProductUrl()): ?>
        <a href="<?php echo $this->getProductUrl()?>" title="<?php echo $this->htmlEscape($this->getProductName()) ?>" class="product-image"><img src="<?php echo $this->getProductThumbnail()->resize(50, 50)->setWatermarkSize('30x10'); ?>" width="50" height="50" alt="<?php echo $this->htmlEscape($this->getProductName()) ?>" /></a>
    <?php else: ?>
        <span class="product-image"><img src="<?php echo $this->getProductThumbnail()->resize(50, 50)->setWatermarkSize('30x10'); ?>" width="50" height="50" alt="<?php echo $this->htmlEscape($this->getProductName()) ?>" /></span>
    <?php endif; ?>
    <div class="product-details">
                <p class="product-name"><?php if ($this->hasProductUrl()): ?><a href="<?php echo $this->getProductUrl() ?>"><?php endif; ?><?php echo $this->htmlEscape($this->getProductName()) ?><?php if ($this->hasProductUrl()): ?></a><?php endif; ?></p>
        <strong><?php echo $this->getQty() ?></strong> x

    <?php if ($canApplyMsrp): ?>

        <span class="map-cart-sidebar-item"><?php echo $this->__('See price before order confirmation.'); ?></span>

    <?php else: ?>

    <?php if ($this->helper('tax')->displayCartPriceExclTax() || $this->helper('tax')->displayCartBothPrices()): ?>
        <?php if ($this->helper('tax')->displayCartBothPrices()): ?>
            <?php echo $this->__('Excl. Tax'); ?>:
        <?php endif; ?>
        <?php if (Mage::helper('weee')->typeOfDisplay($_item, array(0, 1, 4), 'sales')): ?>
            <?php echo $this->helper('checkout')->formatPrice($_item->getCalculationPrice()+$_item->getWeeeTaxAppliedAmount()+$_item->getWeeeTaxDisposition()); ?>
        <?php else: ?>
            <?php echo $this->helper('checkout')->formatPrice($_item->getCalculationPrice()) ?>
        <?php endif; ?>
        <?php if (Mage::helper('weee')->getApplied($_item)): ?>
            <br />
            <?php if (Mage::helper('weee')->typeOfDisplay($_item, 1, 'sales')): ?>
                <small>
                <?php foreach (Mage::helper('weee')->getApplied($_item) as $tax): ?>
                    <span class="nobr"><?php echo $tax['title']; ?>: <?php echo Mage::helper('checkout')->formatPrice($tax['amount'],true,true); ?></span><br />
                <?php endforeach; ?>
                </small>
            <?php elseif (Mage::helper('weee')->typeOfDisplay($_item, 2, 'sales')): ?>
                <?php foreach (Mage::helper('weee')->getApplied($_item) as $tax): ?>
                    <span class="nobr"><small><?php echo $tax['title']; ?>: <?php echo Mage::helper('checkout')->formatPrice($tax['amount_incl_tax'],true,true); ?></small></span><br />
                <?php endforeach; ?>
            <?php elseif (Mage::helper('weee')->typeOfDisplay($_item, 4, 'sales')): ?>
                <small>
                <?php foreach (Mage::helper('weee')->getApplied($_item) as $tax): ?>
                    <span class="nobr"><?php echo $tax['title']; ?>: <?php echo Mage::helper('checkout')->formatPrice($tax['amount_incl_tax'],true,true); ?></span><br />
                <?php endforeach; ?>
                </small>
            <?php endif; ?>
            <?php if (Mage::helper('weee')->typeOfDisplay($_item, 2, 'sales')): ?>
                <span class="nobr"><?php echo Mage::helper('weee')->__('Total'); ?>:<br /> <?php echo $this->helper('checkout')->formatPrice($_item->getCalculationPrice()+$_item->getWeeeTaxAppliedAmount()+$_item->getWeeeTaxDisposition()); ?></span>
            <?php endif; ?>
        <?php endif; ?>
    <?php endif; ?>



    <?php if ($this->helper('tax')->displayCartPriceInclTax() || $this->helper('tax')->displayCartBothPrices()): ?>
        <?php $_incl = $this->helper('checkout')->getPriceInclTax($_item); ?>
        <?php if ($this->helper('tax')->displayCartBothPrices()): ?>
            <br /><?php echo $this->__('Incl. Tax'); ?>:
        <?php endif; ?>
        <?php if (Mage::helper('weee')->typeOfDisplay($_item, array(0, 1, 4), 'sales')): ?>
            <?php echo $this->helper('checkout')->formatPrice($_incl+$_item->getWeeeTaxAppliedAmount()); ?>
        <?php else: ?>
            <?php echo $this->helper('checkout')->formatPrice($_incl-$_item->getWeeeTaxDisposition()) ?>
        <?php endif; ?>
        <?php if (Mage::helper('weee')->getApplied($_item)): ?>
            <br />
            <?php if (Mage::helper('weee')->typeOfDisplay($_item, 1, 'sales')): ?>
                <small>
                <?php foreach (Mage::helper('weee')->getApplied($_item) as $tax): ?>
                    <span class="nobr"><?php echo $tax['title']; ?>: <?php echo Mage::helper('checkout')->formatPrice($tax['amount'],true,true); ?></span><br />
                <?php endforeach; ?>
                </small>
            <?php elseif (Mage::helper('weee')->typeOfDisplay($_item, 2, 'sales')): ?>
                <?php foreach (Mage::helper('weee')->getApplied($_item) as $tax): ?>
                    <span class="nobr"><small><?php echo $tax['title']; ?>: <?php echo Mage::helper('checkout')->formatPrice($tax['amount_incl_tax'],true,true); ?></small></span><br />
                <?php endforeach; ?>
            <?php elseif (Mage::helper('weee')->typeOfDisplay($_item, 4, 'sales')): ?>
                <small>
                <?php foreach (Mage::helper('weee')->getApplied($_item) as $tax): ?>
                    <span class="nobr"><?php echo $tax['title']; ?>: <?php echo Mage::helper('checkout')->formatPrice($tax['amount_incl_tax'],true,true); ?></span><br />
                <?php endforeach; ?>
                </small>
            <?php endif; ?>
            <?php if (Mage::helper('weee')->typeOfDisplay($_item, 2, 'sales')): ?>
                <span class="nobr"><?php echo Mage::helper('weee')->__('Total incl. tax'); ?>:<br /> <?php echo $this->helper('checkout')->formatPrice($_incl+$_item->getWeeeTaxAppliedAmount()); ?></span>
            <?php endif; ?>
        <?php endif; ?>
    <?php endif; ?>

    <?php endif; //Can apply MSRP ?>

        <?php if ($_options = $this->getOptionList()):?>
        <div class="truncated">
          <div class="truncated_full_value">
            <dl class="item-options">
                <?php foreach ($_options as $_option) : ?>
                <dt><?php echo $this->htmlEscape($_option['label']) ?></dt>
                <dd>
                    <?php if (is_array($_option['value'])): ?>
                    <?php echo nl2br(implode("\n", $_option['value'])) ?>
                    <?php else: ?>
                    <?php echo $_option['value'] ?>
                    <?php endif; ?>
                </dd>
                <?php endforeach; ?>
            </dl>
          </div>

        </div>
        <?php endif; ?>
        <a href="<?php 
            $params = $this->getRequest()->getParams();
            if($params['isAjax'] == 1){
                $refererUrl = Mage::registry('referrer_url');
                if (empty($refererUrl)) {
                    $refererUrl = Mage::getBaseUrl();
                }
                $deleteUrl = $this->getUrl(
                    'checkout/cart/delete',
                    array(
                        'id'=>$_item->getId(),
                        Mage_Core_Controller_Front_Action::PARAM_NAME_URL_ENCODED => $this->helper('core/url')->getEncodedUrl($refererUrl)
                    )
                );
            }else{
                $deleteUrl = $this->getDeleteUrl();
            }
            echo $deleteUrl; 
        ?>" title="<?php echo $this->__('Remove This Item') ?>" onclick="return confirm('<?php echo $this->__('Are you sure you would like to remove this item from the shopping cart?') ?>');" class="btn-remove"><?php echo $this->__('Remove This Item') ?></a>
        <?php if ($isVisibleProduct): ?>
        <a href="<?php echo $this->getConfigureUrl() ?>" title="<?php echo $this->__('Edit item') ?>" class="btn-edit"><?php echo $this->__('Edit item')?></a>
        <?php endif ?>

    </div>
</li>
```

Comment: Use callback ajax to refresh mini cart block that trigger after complete add to cart by ajax call. <br />
I know this is not a proper solution but till that time we can use this way.

Comment: I am having the same issue. What code did you change to actually solve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The block `Mage_Checkout_Block_Cart_Item_Renderer` has a function `overrideProductThumbnail` which will update which thumbnail to be used when rendering a product in the cart.

During the `_toHtml` of the grouped product renderer `Mage_Checkout_Block_Cart_Item_Renderer_Grouped` this is called.

```
protected function _toHtml()
{
    $renderer = $this->getRenderedBlock()->getItemRenderer($this->getItem()->getRealProductType());
    $renderer->setItem($this->getItem());
    $renderer->overrideProductThumbnail($this->getProductThumbnail());
    $rendererHtml = $renderer->toHtml();
    $renderer->overrideProductThumbnail(null);
    return $rendererHtml;
}
```

It would seem to me that you have not added the correct item renderers for these product types. See the layout xml file `app/design/frontend/base/default/layout/checkout.xml` for how this can be achieved.

```
<block type="checkout/cart_sidebar" name="cart_sidebar" template="checkout/cart/sidebar.phtml" before="-">
    <action method="addItemRender"><type>simple</type><block>checkout/cart_item_renderer</block><template>checkout/cart/sidebar/default.phtml</template></action>
    <action method="addItemRender"><type>grouped</type><block>checkout/cart_item_renderer_grouped</block><template>checkout/cart/sidebar/default.phtml</template></action>
    <action method="addItemRender"><type>configurable</type><block>checkout/cart_item_renderer_configurable</block><template>checkout/cart/sidebar/default.phtml</template></action>
    <block type="core/text_list" name="cart_sidebar.extra_actions" as="extra_actions" translate="label" module="checkout">
        <label>Shopping Cart Sidebar Extra Actions</label>
    </block>
</block>
```

Comment: This is absolutely the correct answer, as it worked for my project using PolarCore theme and it was not loading the correct thumbnail.  THANK YOU.

Comment: So how did you add the correct renderers to your AJAX response?

Answer (score 2):

For me the issue was in

```
Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Type_Configurable::getProductByAttributes
```

I needed to override method and add 'thumbnail' to the select.  I.e.

```
$productCollection = $this->getUsedProductCollection($product)->addAttributeToSelect('name')->addAttributeToSelect('thumbnail');
```

EE 1.14.x

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
if($product->getTypeId() == 'configurable'){
    $child = $product->getTypeInstance(true)->getProductByAttributes($params['super_attribute'], $product);
    $product = $child;
}
```

This sets the product to the child.

Then use:

```
Mage::helper('catalog/image')->init($product, 'thumbnail');
```

to get the thumbnail for your minicart ^_^